# How to post bin file for OTA in ESP32 without manually opening the page in the browser hosted in the webserver

Tags: curl, iot, esp32, arduino-esp8266, ota

I am trying to trigger OTA update on a webserver hosted on ESP32 externally and **without** opening the browser address of the webserver.

I have seen some examples where the OTA update action can be achieved if the ESP is connected as client, but I am looking for solutions where we can keep the ESP as the webserver only.
Since, this action is assumed to be triggered over network so for that reasons, I will happily accept if any method curl, python/JavaScript http method, node red etc.

This is the server part of  code running in ESP32:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WebServer.h> 
#include <ESPmDNS.h> 
#include <Update.h> 
#include <WiFiManager.h>  
WebServer server(80);


const char* serverIndex = 
"<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>"
"<form method='POST' action='#' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='upload_form'>"
   "<input type='file' name='update'>"
        "<input type='submit' value='Update'>"
    "</form>"
 "<div id='prg'>progress: 0%</div>"
 "<script>"
  "$('form').submit(function(e){"
  "e.preventDefault();"
  "var form = $('#upload_form')[0];"
  "var data = new FormData(form);"
  " $.ajax({"
  "url: '/update',"
  "type: 'POST',"
  "data: data,"
  "contentType: false,"
  "processData:false,"
  "xhr: function() {"
  "var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();"
  "xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {"
  "if (evt.lengthComputable) {"
  "var per = evt.loaded / evt.total;"
  "$('#prg').html('progress: ' + Math.round(per*100) + '%');"
  "}"
  "}, false);"
  "window.location.href ='/login';"
  "return xhr;"
  "},"
  "success:function(d, s) {"
  "console.log('successok !')" 
 "},"
 "error: function (a, b, c) {"
 "}"
 "});"
 "});"
 "</script>";

void setup()
{
//redundant parts have been removed intentionally
WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
int  ct =0;


while (!MDNS.begin(host)) { //http://esp32.local //http://shariq-room.local
    Serial.println("Error setting up MDNS responder!");
    delay(1000);
    ct= ct+1000;

    if (ct>5000) {
      Serial.println("MDNS cannot be set");
      break;
      
    }
  }
  MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);

server.on("/serverIndex", HTTP_GET, []() {
    server.sendHeader("Connection", "close");
    server.send(200, "text/html", serverIndex);
  });
    
        server.on("/update", HTTP_POST, []() {
        server.sendHeader("Connection", "close");
        server.send(200, "text/plain", (Update.hasError()) ? "FAIL" : "OK");
        ESP.restart();
      }, []() {
        Serial.println("OTA started ");
        HTTPUpload& upload = server.upload();
        if (upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_START) {
          Serial.printf("Update: %s\n", upload.filename.c_str());
          if (!Update.begin(UPDATE_SIZE_UNKNOWN)) { //start with max available size
            Update.printError(Serial);
          }
        } else if (upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_WRITE) {
          /* flashing firmware to ESP*/
          if (Update.write(upload.buf, upload.currentSize) != upload.currentSize) {
            Update.printError(Serial);
          }
        } else if (upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_END) {
          if (Update.end(true)) { //true to set the size to the current progress
            Serial.printf("Update Success: %u\nRebooting...\n", upload.totalSize);
          } else {
            Update.printError(Serial);
          }
        }
      });
      server.begin();
}
void loop()
{
  server.handleClient(); 

   delay(400); 
}
```

- Now, this will allow me to select and chose a bin file , if I open
  the localIP and process the OTA if "update" button is clicked.
- But the same "act" will fail to trigger it when using either of python
  script of curl command. The curl command being copied from network section of chrome developer tools.

**Python** script is here.

```
##python
import requests
data = open("home_automate_inc_ota_v.0.2a.ino.esp32.bin", 'rb').read()
files = {'file': open("home_automate_inc_ota_v.0.2a.ino.esp32.bin", 'rb')}
#headers = {    "Content-Type":"application/binary",}
headers= { 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
print("started")
 upload = requests.post("http://192.168.0.7/update", data=data,headers=headers)
#tried below method too
# final_resp = requests.post("http://192.168.0.7/update", files=files, headers=headers)
print("done");
```

But I will get error on either of the post method like
**raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))**

The same when tried in **curl**

```
curl "http://192.168.0.50/update" ^
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" ^
  -H "Accept: */*" ^
  -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----#some hidden webkit data#" ^
  -H "Origin: http://192.168.0.50" ^
  -H "Referer: http://192.168.0.50/backup" ^
  -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" ^
  -H "Cookie: ext_name=#some hidden cookie data#" ^
  --data-raw ^"------#some hidden webkit data#^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"update^\^"; filename=^\^"home_automate_inc_ota_v.0.2a.ino.esp32.bin^\^"^

Content-Type: application/octet-stream^

^

^

------WebKitFormBoundaryPtpk4VGDdfwqS932--^

^" ^
  --compressed ^
  --insecure
```

Gives error as
**curl: (52) Empty reply from server**

Hope I have explained the question well. Please let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Regards,
Shariq

Comment: At the least you need to add a `-X POST` option to `curl` to get it to `POST` the request and not use the `GET` method. You also don't really need the header (`-H`) options given that your web server doesn't look for them.

Comment: Hello..when i added a post without all those headers then it is returning "OK" and simply restarting without trying ota. But I think we are almost there..
this is what i tried
curl "http://192.168.0.50/update" ^
  -X POST^
  --data-raw ^"------WebKitFormBoundary#hidden data#^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"update^\^"; filename=^\^"home_automate_inc_ota_v.0.2a.ino.esp32.bin^\^"^

Content-Type: application/octet-stream^

^

^

------WebKitFormBoundary#hidden data#--^

^" ^
  --compressed ^
  --insecure

Comment: It would help if you actually sent the file with `curl`...

Comment: Hey actually with your suggestions, i tried sending the same file with python BUT WITHOUT HEADERS and it worked like magic :p

Answer (score 2):

As [Romkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670348/romkey) suggested all I had to do was to remove the headers from my request.
I found success with my python code , but curl command failed.
Here is the script.

```
#!Python
import requests
files = {'file': open(r"<full path of the bin file including dir>home_automate_inc_ota_v.0.2a.ino.esp32.bin", 'rb')}

final_resp = requests.post("http://192.168.0.50/update", files=files)
```